# Please what's the difference between the two items in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

Please am confused, what's the difference between the two items?
I want to apply a solution to this code i'm writing here's the link on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NHS1XYApFEOB2ROUpRSH

Thanks For Helping Out. I'm  a total beginner into coding.

```
var myVariable = {};
Object.defineProperties(myVariable, {
    'newProperty1': {
         value: 'valueOfPropertyOne'
     }
});
```

and:

```
var myVariable = [];
Object.defineProperties(myVariable, {
    'newProperty1': {
        value: 'valueOfPropertyOne'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, you end up with a non-array object because you created it with `{}` (an object initializer), and in the second case you end up with an array (which is also an object) because you created it with `[]` (an array initializer). So in the second case, you'll have the magic `length` property, the various things provided by `Array.prototype`, etc.

Typically, you would only use an array when you need those array-specific features.

The reason you can define `newProperty1` on the array is that arrays are objects, and so you can add properties to them. In fact, normal arrays like the one you're using in your second example [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) *(links to a post on my anemic little blog)*, they're just objects backed by `Array.prototype` with a couple of special features.

Comment: Thanks Boss... Youre the best.